# How to store indexable list/collection in an appengine entity?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, indexing, google-cloud-datastore, bigtable

After creating an entity:

```
DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
Entity employee = new Entity("Employee");
```

How to set an index-able list property? like say:

```
employee.setProperty("tag", "manager", "corrupted", ...);
//  "tag" is the property name, 
//  "manager", "corrupted".. are the values in the list.
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [javadoc](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/PropertyContainer#setProperty%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29), you can give a Collection as the second param to setProperty.

E.g

```
List<String> tags = new ArrayList<String>();
tags.add("manager");
tags.add("corrupted");

employee.setProperty("tag", tags);
```